# accessing user edit pages when you are admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently, my edit action in my users controller is like so:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

This works if I want to access my own user profile. However, if I want to access someone else's user profile, this wouldn't work. How should I change this?

Comment: “if I want to access someone else's user profile, this wouldn't work.” But it does. `/users/1/edit` = edit user 1. What you want is to lock down editing so non-admins *cannot* edit.

Comment: Wow yeah I don't know why I thought that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a before action `check_right_user` which checks whether the current user is trying to access his own profile.

```
before_action :check_admin, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]


def check_admin
  unless current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "You're not authorized"
  end
end
```

I assume you have a `current_user` method defined in your `application_controller` or `users_controller` and an `admin` field in your `user` model.

Comment: my bad. The problem is that I want admins to be able to access the edit actions of other users.

Comment: @nachime Updated. Is this what you want?